# How do I add Stack Exchange 2.0 sites to my CV on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I've invested a fair amount of time on [Programmers.StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1254/frank-shearar). I'd like to add my Programmers flair to my CV on careers.stackoverflow, like I could choose to for SU or SF. (I'm sure other people want their TeX badge, or mathematics badge, etc. to show up)

When clicking on the [accounts section](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/accounts) not all Stack Exchange sites are available.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment this is not possible through the accounts page, sorry. It is planned, E.T.A T.B.D.

In the meantime, [you could stick your flair](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/flair) in one of the text fields, but it wouldn't be in the same place as the others of course.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's on the cards. And thanks for the work-around!